# What is the difference between using `ar -rc` vs libtool?

Tags: c, static-libraries

I'm new to c libraries and I'm making a project where I'm not allowed to use `libtool`.

I tried looking online but everything either super confusing or just how to make one with no explanation.

I have a few questions:

- Are `.a` libraries just a collection of `.o` files?
- What is the difference between using `ar -rc` vs `libtool`?
- When the linker goes to link a library does it link the whole `.a` file or just the part it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Are .a libraries just a collection of .o files?

A: Basically, yes.

The object files need to be organized in a specific [archive library format](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/hood0498.aspx).  The linker wouldn't be able to use the archive *UNLESS* it recognized that format. Hence the need for tools like "ar" and "libtool".

> Q: When the linker goes to link a library does it link the whole .a
> file or just the part it needs?*

A: Only the object code that's actually needed is physically added to the executable image.

> Q: What is the difference between using ar -rc vs libtool?

"ar" has been around since the earliest days of Unix; long before "dynamic libraries" were invented (for *nix), before Linus Torvalds ever thought of Linux, or before Gnu existed.  "libtool" is a Gnu tool that supports both dynamic and static libraries, and has a number of features above and beyond basic "ar" functionality.